# The efi filesystem creation failed installing Ubuntu, even selecting "something else" and doing the partitions manually

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in a windows computer. I want windows completely erased.

My problem is that I keep getting an error "The efi filesystem creation in partition #1 ... failed".

[image]

I've tried erasing the disk and selecting "something else". When I select that, this is how I configure it:

[image]

And still get the exact same error.

Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: Try putting a FAT filesystem on the EFI partition instead of an ext4.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!! If I select EFI partition I cannot indicate it as FAT. And If I select a FAT32 system I can't indicate anyplace that's an efi...

Comment: You already show an ESP as sda4? You can only have one per drive/device, although you have have more than one FAT32 with some boot files for grub as a workaround for some configurations. UEFI will only see the one ESP to start booting. Do not confuse a /boot with an ESP. Most desktops do not need /boot.

Comment: Also, the partition sda4, when created should be EF00 for an EFI partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying EVERY suggestion out there, I finally came up with the solution.
I post it here just in case it helps someone.

After trying several times, I did add every partition in different orders, and always partition #1 was the problem.

So I thought that it could be a faulty area in the disk, which effectively was the problem.

So I created a **first empty partition** with a few megabytes, and then all the others. And it worked.

Comment: Signed up just to leave a comment that this was the only thing that worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have made certain to select the partition the /boot/efi is on in that screen and said to use it as system partition I think it is worded. Alternatively in a Terminal just before starting the install, if that did not succeed as mentioned set the type to ef00 with gdisk, an example below.

```
root@zeus-H370M-DS3H:/home/zeus# gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
MBR: not present
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.

Command (? for help): t
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 1
First sector (34-234441614, default = 2048) or    {+-}size{KMGTP}: 40
Last sector (2048-234441614, default = 234441614) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 200M
Current type is 8300 (Linux filesystem)
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): ef00
Changed type of partition to 'EFI system partition'

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data.  THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to   /dev/sda.
The operation has completed successfully.
```

You would use the number 4 for youu disk setup and to check it did indeed do it.

```
root@zeus-H370M-DS3H:~# fdisk -l /dev/sda | grep sda1
/dev/sda1      40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
```

You need to use the `sudo` command in front of the commands I use to do it as root user like I have.