# Disk corrupted?

Tags: boot, partitioning

I want to install Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (for desktop) on my old Dell Inspiton 13-5378, but after first installation grub was loaded with "grub_native_sectors not found" and "grub_file_filters not found" errors.
I'm trying to reinstall Ubuntu but I see "the efi file system creation in partition failed" whenever I choose default ubuntu installation or manual partition.

I also tried to leave 20 mb of unused space as was recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315698/the-efi-filesystem-creation-failed-installing-ubuntu-even-selecting-something?newreg=73c5cb8f13a74ddc8dca0abf3b2d860b) and got same failed error.

The result of booting with Live-CD and creating partition table on disk is: "/dev/sda: unrecognised disk label".

What can I do with it?

Comment: my fault, i though its not important...the version i tried to install is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (for desktop)
@guiverc

Answer (score 0):

"/dev/sda: unrecognised disk label" it mean your disk have to repartitioning you can click on change and chose partition size and filesystem type

Comment: i can not cos gparted says "no partition table found on device" and for creation partition table i have this ("/dev/sda: unrecognised disk label")

Comment: can you follow this (https://askubuntu.com/a/1431688/1698042) please may it helpe you

Comment: as i understood i need to enable iommu.
i checked in the bios and theres no such option (im using dell inspiton 13-5378) but VT for IO and virtuallization are enabled..
@طلعت عتمان

Comment: @ThomasEdward this is bios settinges from dell to install ubuntu (https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131655/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc#BIOS)

Comment: i had same bios settings, except "Enable Legacy option ROMs" that was enabled, tho disabling it give me same result - "the efi file system creation in partition failed" @طلعت عتمان

Comment: Installing Ubuntu on a Dell computer configured for the UEFI BIOS (https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/000141125/xps-13-9343-how-to-install-ubuntu-developer-edition-14-04-on-a-dell-pc-configured-for-the-unified-extensible-firmware-interface-uefi-bios)

Comment: i can not add boot option, got the error "file system not found" @طلعت عتمان

Comment: look at this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/356524/1698042

Comment: I do not suggest standard desktop users need a separate /boot partition, it just is one more partition to manage size of. You need to set device label as gpt with gparted select in menu under device, advanced gpt  over msdos(MBR). Or `sudo parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt`. For UEFI boot, you need the ESP as FAT32 with esp,boot flags 100 to 500MB. You need / (root) not /root. Other partitions are optional. Swap file now used if swap partition not found. And /home or data partition is suggested if drive is very large.

Comment: tray to boot withe boot repair cd may it help to repair your firest installation boot

Comment: i guess i dont need swap partition as i am using ssd.. i did next steps:

1. `sudo parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt`

2. `(parted) -a opt mkpart efi 0% 500MB`

3. `(parted) -a opt mkpart ext4 0% 100%`

however i got the [message](https://pastebin.com/MF0jD6hY).. is theres something wrong im doing? why only 1Mb avialable?..
@oldfred

Comment: Is sda your flash drive? Some systems promote flash drive when rebooted from sdc or whatever to sda and then internal drive is next drive or sdb. Always check drives with fdisk, parted or gdisk before executing any command using device. Device is not always reliable, and thats why UUID used now for mounting in fstab. Also should have mentioned, if drive was MBR converting to gpt would erase it. But most drives since 2012 are gpt as Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode with release of Windows 8 in 2012.

Comment: seems that none of the tools gparted or fdisk actually erase the old partition table of the datacenter. the solution is to erase the first lines of bytes of the disk with : sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdh bs=8M count=8    for more information look at https://serverfault.com/a/802860

Comment: sda is definitely ssd, and stick is always sdb - they have big difference in size, and i have only 2 devices. i dont know if it was mbr, it was bought in 2018.. @oldfred

Comment: it didnt help @طلعت عتمان

Comment: look at this https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/disk-dev-sdh-doesn't-contain-a-valid-partition-table-843399/

Comment: On my system external drives always get promoted to first device on reboot. So sdb becomes sda. You always need to check with partition or fdisk before using device in any command.